# Inserting Google Adsense inbetween content generated with a jQuery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, adsense

I have a search function on my site which returns results from the DB. The results are returned from the DB in JSON, I then append a `DIV` or `SPAN` with the results in a loop.

```
    $("#btnGetresult" ).click(function(e) {
    var browsechapter = $( "#browsechapter" ).val();
    var browsebook = $( "#browsebook" ).val();
    var browseline = $( "#browseline" ).val();
    var version = $( "#version" ).val();

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functionhandlers/getlinecontent.php",
            data: {browseline:browseline, browsechapter:browsechapter, browsebook:browsebook, version:version},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            if(!response.errors && response.result) {
                $('#divcontent').html("");
                $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                    $('#divcontent').append('<p class="resultsclass"><b>'+value[0]+' '+value[1]+':'+value[2]+ '</b></br> '+value[3]+'   <button class="addfavourite" style="background-color:#83d3c9;border:none;color:#fff;padding:5px;"aria-hidden="true">Add to Favourites</button></p></br>');
               });

            } else {
                $('#divsearchresult').html('<b>No lines found</b>');
            }
        });
});
```

How can I insert some adsense script to display between a certain number of results? Pseudo code: after 5th result, insert adsense script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you mean by Adsense script, but maybe a simple condition on the index would be ok.

```
$("#btnGetresult" ).click(function(e) {
var browsechapter = $( "#browsechapter" ).val();
var browsebook = $( "#browsebook" ).val();
var browseline = $( "#browseline" ).val();
var version = $( "#version" ).val();

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functionhandlers/getlinecontent.php",
        data: {browseline:browseline, browsechapter:browsechapter, browsebook:browsebook, version:version},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
    })
    .success(function(response) {
        if(!response.errors && response.result) {
            $('#divcontent').html("");
            $.each(response.result, function( index, value) {
                if(index%5 == 0) {
                $('#divcontent').append('your adsense script');
                }
                $('#divcontent').append('<p class="resultsclass"><b>'+value[0]+' '+value[1]+':'+value[2]+ '</b></br> '+value[3]+'   <button class="addfavourite" style="background-color:#83d3c9;border:none;color:#fff;padding:5px;"aria-hidden="true">Add to Favourites</button></p></br>');
           });

        } else {
            $('#divsearchresult').html('<b>No lines found</b>');
        }
    });
```

});

Which will append "your adsense script" every 5 posts.

EDIT: I used the modulo 5 in the condition to display it every 5 posts, as requested in the comments, you can just edit this condition to a simple equality to display it only one time.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Your code adds the script every 5th time, I am looking to add it only once. By adsense script I meant the adsense advertising code inserted into a page to display an advert.

Comment: No worries, if you want to display it only one time, just change the if condition to : 
if(index == 5) { ... }